# Sort observations in a custom order

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that results from the joins between a few results from a proc univariate.

After some more joins, I have a final dataset with a variable called "Measure", which has the name of certain measures, like 'mean' and 'standard deviation', for example, and other variables each with values for these measures, representing a month in a certain year.

I'd like to sort these measures in a particular order and, for now, I'm doing a proc transpose, doing a retain to stabilish the order I want, and doing another transpose. The problem is that this a really naive solution and I feel it just takes longer than it should take.

Is there a simpler/more effective way to do this sort?

An example of what I want to do, with random values:
What I have:

```
Measures | 2013/01 | 2013/02 | 2013/03
Mean     |   10    |    9    |    11
Std Devi.|   1     |    1    |     1
Median   |   3     |    5    |     4
```

What I want:

```
Measures | 2013/01 | 2013/02 | 2013/03
Std Devi.|   1     |    1    |     1
Median   |   3     |    5    |     4
Mean     |   10    |    9    |    11
```

I hope I was clear enough.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of straightforward solutions.  First, you could simply add a variable that you sort by and then drop.  Don't need to transpose, just do it in the data step or PROC SQL after the join.  `if measures='Mean' then sortorder=3; else if measures='MEdian' then sortorder=2;...` then sort by sortorder and then drop it in the `PROC SORT` step.

Second, if you're using entirely numeric values, you can use `PROC MEANS` to do the sorting for you, with a custom format that defines the order (using `NOTSORTED` and `order=data` on the class statement) and `idgroup` functionality in PROC MEANS to do the sorting and output the right values.  This is overkill in most cases, but if the dataset is *huge* it might be appropriate.

Third, if you're doing the joins in SQL, you can order by the variable that you `input` into a order you want - I can explain that in more detail if you find that the most useful.

Comment: The solutions you offered are already more than enough, thank you very much. But, if it isn't a problem, I'd love it if you could expand on the third solution